# Directives scope when used in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm struggling to figure out how to create a directive within an "ng-repeat" loop.

```
HTML
<article ng-repeat="person in people">
    <div address-count></div>
</article>

JS (doesn't work)
directive('addressCount', function() {
    return {
        template: "Got count " + person.addresses.length
    };    
});
```

I've tried to figure out how to get the scope set correctly, but everything I've tried has failed. How can I access "person" within the template of a directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access `person` as if it were a global variable. `person` is defined on the scope, which can be accessed the same way as in the html:
`template: "Got count {{person.addresses.length}}"`

Comment: Makes total sense! Thanks Ben!